# Unsure how to scrape this betting odds website

Tags: scrapy, screen-scraping

I'm new to python and scrapy. I had hoped I could combine the two to scrape some gambling websites. This is an example;

https://www.oddschecker.com/football/scottish/premiership/kilmarnock-v-aberdeen/winner

If i simply view source html for that page, the main table of odds isn't in the html. Which confuses me greatly. Have tried using scrapy on it but it's got the same issue.

What's going on at that page that nothing can see the data in the table? And what would be an *easy* way to scrape it?

Thanks!

Comment: Try with this selector "#t1". odds table contain this id.

Comment: best way would be to use splash if you are familiar with it, else just go with the simple selenium

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the initial response is all JavaScript. Generally gambling and stats sites don't want to be scraped, and this looks like a means to thwart bots. I would think that this will deep on the difficult end of the pool, and you would likely be better off with something that employs a browser so you can render it.